# Search Javascript Array for string match and output content

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the array below, how do I search for the currencyCode and output currencySign? Example, if I search for "EUR", the output should be ""€"

```
<script>
   var countryMap = {};

    countryMap.AF = {
        currencyCode: "AFN",
        countryName: "Afghanistan",
        currencySign: "؋"   
    };
    countryMap.AX = {
        currencyCode: "EUR",
        countryName: "Åland Islands",
        currencySign: "€"   
    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `countryMap` isn't an array; it's an object.  You're using the fact that Javascript objects are *associative* arrays, but in JS we reserve the term "array" for actual numerically-indexed `Array`s.

For the actual solution, you have several options. Limiting ourselves to vanilla Javascript, you probably have to loop over the elements of `countryMap`, compare the `.currencyCode` value of each element to the one you're looking for, and return the `.currencySign` value from the same element when you find a match.  Something like this should work:

```
function signForCurrency(currencyCode) {
  var country, data;
  for (country in countryMap) {
    // for...in can find things we don't actually care about, 
    // so make sure it's really a key in the map:
    if (countryMap.hasOwnProperty(country)) {
      data = countryMap[country];
      if (data.currencyCode == currencyCode) {
        return data.currencySign;
      }
    }
  }
  // if we get here, we didn't find a match, and the function
  // will return the undefined value
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urhnss6o/2/).

With ECMAScript 2016's new [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) method, you will be able to use a chained expression:

```
function signForCurrency(currencyCode) {
  var data =
    Object.values(countryMap).find(data => data.currencyCode == currencyCode)
  return data ? data.currencySign : undefined;
}
```

Comment: Code is missing the fallback return statement ...if currency code not match

Comment: it would be better to check for `hasOwnProperty` to avoid problems with extra-prototypes

Comment: @Arvind because it will just return `undefined` in that case, which is a reasonable result that doesn't need modification.

Comment: Yeah, I had `in` instead of `of`, just pushing the oriignal problem back one level, but without the typo it would have been ES2015-specific anyway.  Switched to `hasOwnProperty` as @ManasovDaniel sugested.